# How can I print multiple arrays on separate lines using same console.log?

Tags: javascript, arrays, newline, console.log

My output right now is this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39zDA.png)

My code is:

```js
var a = [2, 4];
var b = [5, 6];

console.log(a, "\n", b);
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
[2, 4]
[5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```js
var a = [2, 4];

var b = [5, 6];

console.log('',a,'\n',b)
```

Comment: It works, by the way there is a unwanted space before the output. Is there any way to remove this space? And how does this code work?

Comment: Within `console.log`, when you set the first argument as a `string`, it considers the format as a string. Meaning, arguments that follow the string will also be considered strings. - If you use any other format for the first argument then it won't output the way you expect because it won't assume the rest of your arguments as strings. When using `'\n'` string format is required.

Comment: Your solution is so much close to my expected output and I think that's the best solution for my expected output. So there's no way to remove the space before the output. Thanks for answer. Take love.

Comment: I have an idea to remove the space but I'm currently out for lunch. Will update when I'm back.  :)

Comment: Wow, it would be great! I am waiting for reply.

Comment: So unfortunately the space cannot be removed. When you use an empty string within `console.log` a `space-symbol` is added by default. I tried a few other [string escape codes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) to remove the default space but it does not work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use

var a = [2, 4];

var b = [5, 6];

console.log(a + "\n" + b);

It's working for me.

Comment: It returns output as string!

Comment: Okay, then you can write console.log twice:
console.log(a);
console.log(b);

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
console.log(`${a}\n${b}`);
```

Comment: It returns as string, i want the output as array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`array.toString()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp) function.

```js
var a = [2, 4];
var b = [5, 6];

console.log(a.toString() + '\n' + b.toString())
```

This code would return:

```
2,4
5,6
```